# ci-merchant.org - Add custom data to paypal express transaction

Tags: php, codeigniter, payment-gateway, ci-merchant

Im using the ci-merchant library [ci-merchant](http://ci-merchant.org/) and it all works fine except that Im just passing the order total to paypal.

Is there a way to specify the shipping amount, and /or other custom attributes so when customers get referred to Paypal there is an itemized list so they know what they are paying for.

This is my existing code:

```
    $params = array(
            'amount' => 50.00,
            'currency' =>  'USD',
            'return_url' => 'mysite.com/return/' . $order_id,
            'notify_url' => 'mysite.com/notify/' . $order_id,
            );


    $response  = $this->merchant->purchase($params);
```

What I would like to do is something like:

```
    $params = array(
            'amount' => 40.00,
            'shipping' => 10.00,
            'currency' =>  'USD',
            'return_url' => 'mysite.com/return/' . $order_id,
            'notify_url' => 'mysite.com/notify/' . $order_id,
            );


    $response  = $this->merchant->purchase($params);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify a file into the library like specified here, and it allows you to pass an array of items with the classic data required when calling purchase() method.

https://github.com/guillermofr/ci-merchant/commit/70ea1a2864971078b3b67e5ca1051be174f23fa0#commitcomment-3642787

The array is formatted like this :

```
$params = array(
        'amount' => 40.00,
        'currency' =>  'USD',
        'return_url' => 'mysite.com/return/' . $order_id,
        'notify_url' => 'mysite.com/notify/' . $order_id,
        'items' => array(
            array(  
              'name'=>'',
              'desc'=>'',
              'amt'=>,
              'qty'=>
           )
        )
 );
```

But remember that ci-merchant is no longer supported. You better use Omnipay.

Comment: My bad for the lot of edits. I tried to be the clearest possible. Btw, note that shipping fees cannot be displayed as far as I know. They're included into the global amount of the transaction.

Comment: thanks, its ok that I dont display shipping, i can add it as one of the items

Comment: After looking to the link I provided to you, shipping fees are applicable, with the optional per-item parameter 'shippingamt' => 0.00

Comment: ThankYou very very much you saved our Life.................................................bless you